# elasticsearch php search exists

Tags: php, elasticsearch

How might one do the following request

```
GET /giata_index/giata_type/_search/exists
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "status": 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "ids": "26744"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

with ElasticSearch's PHP library?

I have played around with the exists endpoint, but as it turns out, that can only check whether a specific uid is existant or not. So I guess I need to do a search. But I can't find a parameter in the [Search endpoints's](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/blob/master/src/Elasticsearch/Endpoints/Search.php) whitelist that would allow a simple check for exists or not.

The reason why I would like to avoid getting the entire document and just ask whether it exists or not is because I have multiple hundreds of thousands of imports and just as many documents in ES, so I would like it to put as little work into it as possible.

Note: I have also looked into head requests that are possible via HTTP requests (only retrieve the header of a document - either 200 or 404). But that would probably only exist for requests via HTTP.

If worse comes to worse I could shoot a curl via php and simply do it via HTTP. But I would prefer it otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems indeed that there's no endpoint voor search exists, but I think you use a simple alternative:

Use an empty "fields" array. And count the results of your query. If == 0: false. If > 0: true

```
GET /giata_index/giata_type/_search
{
    "fields": [],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "status": 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "ids": "26744"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

An other alternative is to use _count : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/search-count.html

Comment: Yep...could have thought of this myself. I chose the variant with empty fields array. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with the [latest 2.x version](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/blob/master/src/Elasticsearch/Endpoints/SearchExists.php).
Code sample could be something like this:

```
$clientBuilder = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create();
// Additional client options, hosts, etc.
$client = $clientBuilder->build();

$index = 'your_index';
$type = 'your_type';

$params = [
  'index' => $index,
  'type'  => $type,
  'body'  => [
    'query' => [
      'bool' => [
        'must' => [
          [
            'term' => [
              "status" => 2
            ]
          ],
          [
            'term' => [
              'ids' => "26744"
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ];

try {
  $client->searchExists($params);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Not found. You might want to return FALSE if wrapped in a function.
  // return FALSE;
}
// Found.
```

It is worth noting that if search is not wrapped in try/catch block it can break execution and throw an exception (status code 4xx if not found).
Also, it can not be used effectively in [future mode](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_future_mode.html#_caveats_to_future_mode).